# Cant remove padding in table header column using bootstrap 3 jquery-calendar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-week-calendar

i have the following issue. I created a calendar using the jquery-week-calendar by themouette and also i use jquery. The thing is that the hour column is not aligned with the slot columns as you can see in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeXp3/5/) (fiddle will not work in chrome, tried it in firefox and works no problem).

If i use the tag !important in the css

```
td.wc-time-header-cell {
    /* padding: 5px !important;  this works for timeslotsPerHour: 4*/
    padding-top: 0 !important; 
    /* height: 79px !important; this works for timeslotsPerHour: 4 */
}
```

it solves the issue, but when i change the timeslotsPerHour parameter from 2 to 4 or any other value it brakes. I dont know how to fix this. I also tried the following reset.css i found in the project home.

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/master/full_demo/reset.css

but still no go. Could u guys help me out?

i also tried with

```
td.wc-time-header-cell {
    padding-top: 0 !important; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

EDIT:

found out that if disabling the following lines in the css worked:

```
* {
  /* -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
```

Comment: Checked the Fiddle, doesn't seem to be working in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: fixed it. dont know why the bootstrap js was not saved in the chrome session.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a stupid answer, but I don't think you can use a value without a unit (px in this case). Try

```
padding-top: 0px
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: That would not make a difference. If you're using a zero value, it doesn't matter what unit you're using.